# ie7: doesnt load eot fontface

Tags: internet-explorer-7, font-face, eot

as i looked into the network tab of ie9 (in ie7 mode) then i saw that there were no eot files loaded but in ie8 and ie9

how can i solve this problem?

i am using windows 7 and ie9 in ie7 mode
in ie6 and ie8 they font loads but not ie7

i used the css code by fontsquirrel.com

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'SansumiExtraBoldRegular';
src: url('../fonts/Sansumi-ExtraBold-webfont.eot');
src: url('../fonts/Sansumi-ExtraBold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../fonts/Sansumi-ExtraBold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../fonts/Sansumi-ExtraBold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../fonts/Sansumi-ExtraBold-webfont.svg#SansumiExtraBoldRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```